# Performance issue while generating shasum for every individual row in a given file

Tags: performance, aix, sha

I am trying to generate a sha256 hash for a particular column in every row. I tried generating the a sha256hash using the solution provided by fellow members in this group. Thanks to Ravinder Singh. I used the same exact code except for the actual sha command. For AIX it is shasum -a 256.

Code:

```
awk -F"|" -v var="10" '
    NR==1;
    NR>1{
        "echo "$2"|shasum -a 256" | getline shaoutput;
        split(shaoutput, sha, " ");
        print $1, $2, sha[1]
    }' OFS="|" inputfile.dat >outputfile.dat
```

This works perfectly. the only problem is that the performance of this code is very slow. It is currently taking a minute for 1000 records. I need to generate a large amount of hash as a one time thing for over 10 million records. Is there anyway the performance can be improved?

I tried using perl like Lorinczy Zsigmond suggested. Now i can process a million rows in under 10 secs.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
my $inputfile = 'inputfile.dat';
open(my $fh,'<',$inputfile)
 or die "Could not open file '$inputfile' $!";
while (my $row = <$fh>){
chomp $row;
my @fields=split /\|/,$row;
print $fields[0];
print "|";
print $fields[1];
print "|";
print sha256_hex($fields[1]);
print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Starting separate process for every file is slow, use `xargs`. Also use `bash` instead of `ksh`, it is way faster. Mind you, shell scripts are slow by design. Every Unix has Perl, use it.

Comment: I tried your using perl like you suggested and i cant believe the difference. million rows in under 10 secs. Thank you. I posted the code i used for future use in my original post itself. Thanks everyone.